# c# - Reading lines from text file and adding to listbox

Tags: c#

I think my question is simple. I've searched but not found a solution for the method that I'm actually using.
I save the content of a listbox into a text file with success, but I'm having problem on load.
For create the file, I use:

```
using(StreamWriter file = File.CreateText(path))
```

To write the content from the listbox to file, I use:

```
foreach (string content in listDOF.Items)
{
    file.WriteLine(content);
}
```

This works very well.
Now, I just need load the saved content with succes.
I've tried:

```
if (File.Exists(filesrc))
{
    File.OpenRead(filesrc);
    string[] line = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filesrc);
    listDOF.Items.Add(line);
}
```

But this does not work and give me an exception.
How to do this correctily? Thanks all in advance! :)

Comment: Remove `File.OpenRead(filesrc);`, it is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks too @dasblinkenlight. This line was giving me a second exception in the save operation. Removing it and adding the Items.AddRange made my program works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @Hypister For future reference, when you get an exception, post it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding an array of strings. The method to use is [AddRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z018s5az(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filesrc);
listDOF.Items.AddRange(lines);
```

The File.OpenRead is not needed. You could remove that line